# Convert JSON String to Dictionary of type [String: Any] as Parameters to pass in Alamofire Request

Tags: json, dictionary, alamofire, objectmapper, swift5

I'm trying to convert a JSON Object to a dictionary of type [String: Any]. But I can't find any possible methods to do so. Anyone, please help to do the same. 
I'm using Alamofire for networking. Alamofire accepting request parameters as dictionary. So I just need to send the request parameters. But the problem is, the request parameters are in a JSON String. So I need to convert that JSON String to Dictionary of type [String: Any].
A sample request parameter is given below..

```
{
"name": "Arun",
"age": "12",
"Address": [
{
  "house_name": "xxxx",
  "street": "xxxx",
  "district": "xxxx",
  "state": "xxxxx"
 },
 {
  "house_name": "xxxx",
  "street": "xxxx",
  "district": "xxxx",
  "state": "xxxxx"
 }
]
}
```

How can i convert the above JSON Strig to Dictionary of type [String: Any]?